# replace substring if follows number, eg screen resolution, php

Tags: php, regex, numbers, resolutions

I have looked everywhere but I am stuck and need some help.
I believe I need a regex to replace a quote `"` (for inches) at the end of a number.
For example `21.5"` with `21.5inch`
I need to do it only if the `"` has a number before it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there possible whitespaces between the number and quote?

Comment: Corrected sentences to make problem more clear and  highlighted special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for this task is

```
(\d)"
```

Here is [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yB3zB2/1) with explanation

Comment: Wrong! `\d` does not includes decimal notation `.` Also, it does not forgive  space between digit and `"`.

Comment: Who needs decimal character ?

Comment: Check OP's post. He himself asked for `21.5inch`.

Comment: The  regex provided works for above string, I do not see any issue.

Comment: No. In your demo link, it matches only `5`.

Comment: @haywire you need to look at how the substitution is being used at the bottom of the demo.

Comment: @chris85 Oh I never noticed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=\d)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/lC9tZ7/2

It should grab the " as long as it follows a digit.

If it can have spaces between the digit and ", try this:

```
(?<=\d)\s*"
```

https://regex101.com/r/cT1bF7/3

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\d+\.{0,1}\d+)\s*"`

Explanation: Lets try matching `21.54  inch`

1. `\d+` matches `21`
2. `\.{0,1}` escapes decimal notation and matches if there's a `.` atleast 0 times (i.e., there is no decimal at all) and atmost 1 times (i.e., a number can only have at most 1 decimal). So, we have so far matched `21.`
3. `\d+` matches the remaining `54`. So far matched `21.54`
4. `\s*` forgives if there is any space followed by the number
5. `"` finally ensures that the number is followed by the inch notation.

Check this [demo link here](https://regex101.com/r/jD6hJ6/1).

Comment: You can safely omit `\s*` if there should not be any space between the number and `"`

Comment: You can use the `?` in place of `{0,1}`.